# Word Split Algorithm into Prefix Stem and Suffix

Tags: c#, algorithm, split

I have a problem where I need to split an input string into possible `Prefix`, `Stem` and `Suffix`.

The rules are:

`Prefix` = 0-4 chars

`Stem` = 1-* chars

`Suffix` = 0-6 chars.

Say I have input "wbAlErbyp" it needs to be split so (incomplete sample) :

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

[image]

EDIT 1 :

Okay here is my old solution (its very long and unprofessional), I do not understand it anymore and would like to redesign.

```
    public static List<string> GetMatches(string inputTextArabic)
    {
        // store matches/results here
        List<string> results = new List<string>();

        char[] arabicChars = inputTextArabic.ToCharArray();

        // convert all the arabic chars from array
        // into latin chars in array
        string latString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < arabicChars.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (arabicChars[i])
            {
                #region ARABIC TO LATIN TABLE
                case 'ا':
                    latString += "A";
                    break;
                case 'آ':
                    latString += "|";
                    break;
                case 'ؤ':
                    latString += "&";
                    break;
                case 'ئ':
                    latString += "}";
                    break;
                case 'أ':
                    latString += ">";
                    break;
                case 'إ':
                    latString += "<";
                    break;
                case 'ء':
                    latString += @"\";
                    break;
                case 'ب':
                    latString += "b";
                    break;
                case 'ت':
                    latString += "t";
                    break;
                case 'ة':
                    latString += "p";
                    break;
                case 'ث':
                    latString += "v";
                    break;
                case 'ج':
                    latString += "j";
                    break;
                case 'ح':
                    latString += "H";
                    break;
                case 'خ':
                    latString += "x";
                    break;
                case 'د':
                    latString += "d";
                    break;
                case 'ذ':
                    latString += "*";
                    break;
                case 'ر':
                    latString += "r";
                    break;
                case 'ز':
                    latString += "z";
                    break;
                case 'س':
                    latString += "s";
                    break;
                case 'ش':
                    latString += "$";
                    break;
                case 'ص':
                    latString += "S";
                    break;
                case 'ض':
                    latString += "D";
                    break;
                case 'ط':
                    latString += "T";
                    break;
                case 'ظ':
                    latString += "Z";
                    break;
                case 'ع':
                    latString += "E";
                    break;
                case 'غ':
                    latString += "g";
                    break;
                case 'ـ':
                    latString += "_";
                    break;
                case 'ف':
                    latString += "f";
                    break;
                case 'ق':
                    latString += "q";
                    break;
                case 'ك':
                    latString += "k";
                    break;
                case 'ل':
                    latString += "l";
                    break;
                case 'م':
                    latString += "m";
                    break;
                case 'ن':
                    latString += "n";
                    break;
                case 'ه':
                    latString += "h";
                    break;
                case 'و':
                    latString += "w";
                    break;
                case 'ى':
                    latString += "Y";
                    break;
                case 'ي':
                    latString += "y";
                    break;
                case 'ً':
                    latString += "F";
                    break;
                case 'ٌ':
                    latString += "N";
                    break;
                case 'ٍ':
                    latString += "K";
                    break;
                case 'َ':
                    latString += "a";
                    break;
                case 'ُ':
                    latString += "u";
                    break;
                case 'ِ':
                    latString += "i";
                    break;
                case 'ّ':
                    latString += "~";
                    break;
                case 'ْ':
                    latString += "o";
                    break;
                #endregion
            }
        }

        // loop thru different stem sizes
        // stem is 1-*
        int lenWord = latString.Length;
        for (int lenStem = 1; lenStem <= lenWord; lenStem++)
        {

            // set max prefix size, strd is 4 but could be
            // less depending on word size
            int lenPrefMax = 4;
            if (lenWord - lenStem < lenPrefMax)
            {
                lenPrefMax = lenWord - lenStem;
            }

            // loop thru different prefix sizes
            // based on the max above
            for (int lenPref = 0; lenPref <= lenPrefMax; lenPref++)
            {
                // set suffix max, std is 6, but could be
                // less depending on word size
                int lenSuffMax = 6;
                if (lenWord - lenStem - lenPref < lenSuffMax)
                {
                    lenSuffMax = lenWord - lenStem - lenPref;
                }

                // loop thru different suffix sizes
                // based on the max above
                for (int lenSuff = 0; lenSuff <= lenSuffMax; lenSuff++)
                {
                    // if sum of parts doesnt equal word size
                    // it means its not a proper match, thus skip
                    if (lenPref + lenStem + lenSuff < lenWord)
                        continue;

                    // otherwise, these are the possible word bits
                    string prefix = latString.Substring(0, lenPref);
                    string stem = latString.Substring(lenPref, lenStem);
                    string suffix = latString.Substring(lenPref + lenStem, lenSuff);

                    // now see if they all exist in the relevant places
                    List<WordBit> prefMatches = (from x in prefixes where x.NoVowels == prefix select x).Distinct().ToList();
                    List<WordBit> stemMatches = (from x in stems where x.NoVowels == stem select x).Distinct().ToList();
                    List<WordBit> suffMatches = (from x in suffixes where x.NoVowels == suffix select x).Distinct().ToList();

                    if (!(prefMatches.Count > 0 && stemMatches.Count > 0 && suffMatches.Count > 0))
                        break;                          

                    // Now that they are found, see if they go together
                    // For each prefix, loop through every stem
                    foreach(WordBit prefMatch in prefMatches)
                    {                       
                        // for each stem, loop through all suffixes
                        foreach (WordBit stemMatch in stemMatches)
                        {
                            // Now we know there is a prefix, suffix and stem
                            foreach (WordBit suffMatch in suffMatches)
                            {
                                // get their types
                                string prefType = prefMatch.Type;
                                string stemType = stemMatch.Type;
                                string suffType = suffMatch.Type;

                                // find out if the types are compatible
                                bool prefStemConnects = (from x in prefixStemConns where x.Type1 == prefType && x.Type2 == stemType select x).Count() > 0;
                                bool stemSuffConnects = (from x in stemSuffixConns where x.Type1 == stemType && x.Type2 == suffType select x).Count() > 0;
                                bool prefSuffConnects = (from x in prefixSuffixConns where x.Type1 == prefType && x.Type2 == suffType select x).Count() > 0;

                                // they all connect
                                // we have found a match!
                                if (prefStemConnects && stemSuffConnects && prefStemConnects)
                                {

                                    Match match = new Match();
                                    //match.MatchMeaning = "";

                                    // 1. prefix
                                    // 2. stem
                                    // 3. 
                                //takeplusesout
                                    match.MatchMeaning = match.RootMeaning = Regex.Match(stemMatch.Extra, @"^.*?(?=\s\s|$)").ToString();

                                    // [fem.sg.] = I 


                                    match.SuffixInfo = Regex.Match(suffMatch.Extra, @"^.*?(?=\s\s)").ToString();
                                    if (match.SuffixInfo != "")
                                    {
                                        if (match.SuffixInfo.Contains("<verb>"))
                                        {
                                            match.MatchMeaning = match.SuffixInfo.Replace("<verb>", match.RootMeaning);
                                            match.SuffixInfo = "";
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            match.MatchMeaning = match.MatchMeaning + " " + match.SuffixInfo;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    // Get 1st part of prefix
                                    match.PrefixInfo = Regex.Match(prefMatch.Extra, @"^.*?(?=\s|\s\s|$)").ToString();
                                    if (match.PrefixInfo != "")
                                    {
                                        match.MatchMeaning = match.PrefixInfo + " " + match.RootMeaning + " " + match.SuffixInfo;
                                    }

                                    //results.Add(prefMatch.Extra + "--" + stemMatch.Extra + "--" + suffMatch.Extra);
                                    //if (beforeMeaning != "")
                                    //   beforeMeaning += " ";

                                    results.Add(match.MatchMeaning);


                                    Debug.Print("_____________________________________________________________________________________");
                                    Debug.Print(prefMatch.NoVowels + "\t\t" + prefMatch.Vowels + "\t\t" + prefMatch.Type + "\t\t" + prefMatch.Extra);
                                    Debug.Print(stemMatch.NoVowels + "\t\t" + stemMatch.Vowels + "\t\t" + stemMatch.Type + "\t\t" + stemMatch.Extra);
                                    Debug.Print(suffMatch.NoVowels + "\t\t" + suffMatch.Vowels + "\t\t" + suffMatch.Type + "\t\t" + suffMatch.Extra);
                                    Debug.Print("______________________________________________________________________________________");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return results;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?  If you show some initial effort, you are more likely to get help.

Comment: Not enough info.  How do you know where the prefix ends and the stem begins? Same thing goes for the suffix.  Without that info, you can't do it.

Comment: Okay wait up Ill post my current algorithm. Will, you will not know, you make all possible combinations, then Ill do a search on my data.

Comment: That part of your code is already close to optimal. It's the rest of your code that's bad. So I don't really get what your question is after the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just build two nested loops iterating over all possible prefix and suffix lengths.

```
string s="wbAlErbyp";

const int maxPrefixLength = 4;
const int maxSuffixLength = 6;
const int minStemLength = 1;

for(int prefixLength = 0; (prefixLength + minStemLength <= s.Length) && (prefixLength<=maxPrefixLength); prefixLength++)
    for(int suffixLength = 0; (suffixLength + prefixLength + minStemLength <= s.Length) && (suffixLength<=maxSuffixLength); suffixLength++)
    {
        string prefix = s.Substring(0, prefixLength);
        string suffix = s.Substring(s.Length-suffixLength);
        string stem   = s.Substring(prefixLength, s.Length-suffixLength-prefixLength);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",prefix,stem, suffix);
    }
```

Comment: Genius! How did you approach this problem?

Comment: @MuhammadA Almost the same way you did. Only significant difference is that I pushed the conditions into the `for` abortion condition.